# Как сделать рандомное выпадение предмета в init

Tags: c#, unity3d

Когда ты нажимаешь на сундук то будет появляться рандомный предмет из заданного списка

Comment: класс [Random и его метод Next](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=netcore-3.1) в помощь

Answer (score 0):

```cs
public GameObject[] Items;//Добавьте предметы из окна Inspector
public GameObject Chest;
private bool IsChestOpened = false;

public void OpenChest()
{
    if(!IsChestOpened)
    {
        GameObject Loot = Instantiate(Items[Random.Range(0, Items.Length)]);
        IsChestOpened = true;
        Loot.transform.localPosition = Chest.transform.localPosition;
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Самый умный что ли? Ты уже открыл этот сундук.");
    }
}
```